# Cannot cast from Any? to NSSize?

Tags: casting, swift3, option-type

I am trying to make a cast from `Any?` to `NSSize?`, more precisely if I write this:

```
Swift.print(screenDescription![NSDeviceResolution])
```

in the console I get this:

[image]

but if I write this:

```
let dotsPerInch = screenDescription![NSDeviceResolution] as? NSSize
```

the value of dotsPerInch becomes `nil` and not `{144,144}`.

Why?

Comment: Could this be related to SE-0139? https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md

Comment: If yes how to fix the code?

Comment: Try casting to `NSValue` first. Also, if you force the cast (`as!`), what is the error thrown?

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'NSConcreteValue' (0x100dff888) to '__C.CGSize' (0x100632168).
Could not cast value of type 'NSConcreteValue' (0x100dff888) to '__C.CGSize' (0x100632168).
2016-11-03 21:44:33.632961 myApp[9436:967999] Could not cast value of type 'NSConcreteValue' (0x100dff888) to '__C.CGSize' (0x100632168).
2016-11-03 21:44:33.632966 MyApp[9436:967986] Could not cast value of type 'NSConcreteValue' (0x100dff888) to '__C.CGSize' (0x100632168).

Comment: OK, so cast it to `NSValue` and then use the `cgSizeValue` property to obtain the size.

Comment: WORKS! Thank you. I have an identical problem with screenDescription!["NSScreenNumber"] as! CGDirectDisplayID, I try immediately (I think it is a Int32 with a bizarre name)

Comment: @LeoNatan for "NSScreenNumber" I want to obtain a CGDirectDisplayID, which is an Int64. What have I to call now? I can't find any method like "longLongValue"

Comment: In this case, cast to NSNumber, where you do have such a method.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber

Comment: Works! By the way, CGDirectDisplayID IS a uint32

Comment: Added as an answer. Please accept if it has solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a compiler bug.
Cast to `NSValue` first, then use the `cgSizeValue` property to obtain the size on iOS or the `sizeValue` property on macOS.